# Not able to execute PHP file in hostpaedia using exec command

Tags: php, cron, runtime-error, execution

I have a shared hosting account in **hostpaedia**. I had set my cronjob for a php file. It was working fine until a day it suddenly stop working. When tried to run manually that file using command

```
exec('/usr/bin/php -q /home/mobiles/cron/mobiles/flipkart/feed.php',$output);
```

I didn't got any result but when i run the following command

```
exec('ps aux|grep php',$output);
```

I Got this as output

[image]

I am not able to figure out what is happening. I am not able to access my website. It shows a blank page on my website. I don't know how to solve these.
Please help on the issue

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your php script. It will output info about errors.

Comment: Thnx for the reply.. I tried but the issue still exist . I doubt if there is any fault with the server. Are there any other debugging  tricks i can try